# Parse XML special characters?

Tags: android, android-manifest

From the last 2 days I am searching that how to parse XML with special chars like !@#$%^&*()':;", but I am not getting anything sufficient that how to implement it.. Can anyone pls suggest me something..how can I do this??

Comment: did you get the soultion to your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try something like [this](http://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/J6d_xml.html), that is giving the reference for that special character.

```
Character Reference

&   -   &amp;
<   -   &lt;
>   -   &gt;
"   -   &quot;
'   -   &apos;
```

**UPDATE:**

I had already answered in your question here so have a look at the [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134317/sax-parsing-of-character/8137682#8137682).

Comment: I am using XML SAX parser and it is parsing all the chars except & and <...now I am confused that how to handle them?

Comment: Please check my updated answer, and let me know if you get any problem further.

Answer (score 1):

```
documentBuilder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
document = documentBuilder.parse(inputSource);
document.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

The normalize method can handle special characters and entities for you.

> public abstract void normalize ()
>
> Added in API level 1
>
> Puts all Text nodes in the full depth of the sub-tree underneath this
>   Node, including attribute nodes, into a "normal" form where only
>   structure (e.g., elements, comments, processing instructions, CDATA
>   sections, and entity references) separates Text nodes, i.e., there are
>   neither adjacent Text nodes nor empty Text nodes. This can be used to
>   ensure that the DOM view of a document is the same as if it were saved
>   and re-loaded, and is useful when operations (such as XPointer
>   [XPointer] lookups) that depend on a particular document tree
>   structure are to be used. If the parameter "normalize-characters" of
>   the DOMConfiguration object attached to the Node.ownerDocument is
>   true, this method will also fully normalize the characters of the Text
>   nodes.
>
> Note: In cases where the document contains CDATASections, the
>   normalize operation alone may not be sufficient, since XPointers do
>   not differentiate between Text nodes and CDATASection nodes.

Answer (score 0):

1. A valid XML file should *not* have any of these characters "&", "<", ">" or "@".  It should instead have the named entities "&amp", "&lt", "&gt", "&reg", "&quot", "&apos", etc:

[xml parsing with "&amp;", "&reg;", but still getting errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7787567/xml-parsing-with-amp-reg-but-still-getting-errors)

2. If the XML file is valid then parsing (using "android.util.XML", I presume), should "just work".

These links might also help:

- [Parsing invalid ampersands with Android's XmlPullParsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268895/parsing-invalid-ampersands-with-androids-xmlpullparsers)
- http://developer.android.com/reference/org/xmlpull/v1/XmlPullParser.html

Comment: I am using XML SAX parser and it is parsing all the chars except & and <...now I ma confused that how to handle them?

Answer (score 0):

```
 public void XmlParsing(String questions_xml)
{
    try {

        /** Handling XML */
        SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
        SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
        XMLReader xr = sp.getXMLReader();

        /** Create handler to handle XML Tags ( extends DefaultHandler ) */
        MyXmlHandler myXMLHandler = new MyXmlHandler();
        xr.setContentHandler(myXMLHandler);

        xr.parse( new InputSource(new StringReader(questions_xml)));


        } catch (Exception e) {
            String err = (e.getMessage()==null)?"XMLParsing exception":e.getMessage();
            Log.e("XMLParsing Exception",err); 
        }


}
now when I am trying to parse & then my app crashes?
```

Comment: or it displays only strings priror to &

Answer (score 0):

There is a [free command line tool](http://hll.nu/purchase/GetFreeXPL.htm) for transforming files with special characters in text to valid XML. It also assures that the file encoding matches what is specified in the declaration.

There is also a Java developer suite that allows you to use the parser to parse such files (called XPL) as an alternative to XML or a pre-process into XML. It uses a StAX-like process called StAX-PL.