# Special characters in Text node not getting parsed by SAX's characters() method

Tags: java, android, xml, xml-parsing, sax

I'm making an android application in which I'm parsing an XML using SAX parser.

In the XML there is tag:

```xml
<title>Deals &amp; Dealmakers: Technology, media and communications M&amp;A </title>
```

As you can see it contains some special charters like `&amp;`

The issue is I'm using SAX's implicit method:

```java
@Override
public void characters(char[] ch, int start, int length) throws SAXException{}
```

Here, the parameter 'char[] ch' is supposed to fetch the entire line `Deals &amp; Dealmakers: Technology, media and communications M&amp;A`
But it is only getting "Deals ".

How can I solve this issue?

One issue might be because of the way I'm passing the XML to the SAX parser. Do I need to change the encoding or format?

Currently, I'm passing the XML as `InputStream` & using the below code:

```java
HttpResponse httpResponse = utils.sendRequestAndGetHTTPResponse(URL);
if (httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
    HttpEntity entity = httpResponse.getEntity();
    InputStream in = entity.getContent();
    parseResponse(in);
}


// Inside parseResponse method:
try {
    SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
    SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
    XMLReader xmlReader = sp.getXMLReader();

    MyHandler handler = new MyHandler();
    xmlReader.setContentHandler(handler);
    xmlReader.parse(new InputSource(in));
} catch (Exception e) {
}
```

Comment: refer this Link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2838099/android-sax-parser-not-getting-full-text-from-between-tags & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8134317/sax-parsing-of-character

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Here, the parameter 'char[] ch' is supposed to fetch the entire line Deals & Dealmakers: Technology, media and communications M&A But it is only getting "Deals ".

You seem to be assuming that you'll get the whole text in one call. There's no guarantee of that. I strongly suspect that your `characters` method will be called multiple times for the same text node, which is valid for the parser to do. You need to make sure your code handles that.

From the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/org/xml/sax/ContentHandler.html#characters%28char%5B%5D,%20int,%20int%29):

> SAX parsers may return all contiguous character data in a single chunk, or they may split it into several chunks; however, all of the characters in any single event must come from the same external entity so that the Locator provides useful information.

There *may* be a feature you can set to ensure you get all the data in one go; I'm not sure.

Comment: thanks using stringbuilder's append method as suggested in http://stackoverflow.com/a/2838338/1433826

Answer (score 0):

I guess UTF-8 is exactly the problem . In the file,you parsing  the encoding is defined as ISO-8859-1

so just try following code:

```
InputSource is = new InputSource(yourInputStream);
is.setEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
xmlReader.parse(is);
```

hope this helps.